# How to pass property from Gradle to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource({"classpath:${properties.file}"})
public class AppConfiguration {
}
```

I need to pass to spring "properties.file" property, this property is dynamically changed in gradle build based on tasks graph.

Comment: How do you want to pass it in? When you use `bootRun`, when you're building your application's jar, something else?

Comment: as long as you dont change file name and drop it in the classpath(eg. main\resources) it should work.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson when I run "gradlew run" or "gradlew test"

Comment: @kuhajeyan yeap, but it is not static, it should be different depending on gradle parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
ext {
    dynamicResources = "$buildDir/dynamicResources"
    prop1 = 'value1'
    prop2 = 'value2'
}
dependencies {
    runtime files(dynamicResources)
}
task createDynamicResources {
    inputs.property 'prop1', prop1
    inputs.property 'prop2', prop2
    outputs.dir dynamicResources
    doLast {
        mkdir dynamicResources
        file("$dynamicResources/foo.properties").text = """
prop1=${prop1} 
prop2=${prop2}             
        """
    }
}
bootRun.dependsOn createDynamicResources
```

Now foo.properties will be on the runtime classpath of bootRun

See [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-share/blob/master/build.gradle#L33) for a similar pattern